# using nginx try_files and autoindex together

Tags: nginx, rewrite, directoryindex

I have the following server configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    root /var/www/;

    location /calendars/ {
        autoindex on;
        try_files $uri.ics $uri =404;
    }
}
```

If would expect to get the `autoindex` page on visiting `http://example.com/calendars/`, however I get an `404 File not found` error instead.

I want the server do something like this pseudo-code:

```
if($uri is directory) {
    if(one of index pages exists in directory) {
        show index page;
    } else {
        show autoindex page;
    }
} else {
    if($uri.ics exists) {
        show $uri.ics;
    } else if($uri exists) {
        show $uri;
    } else {
        show 404 page;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also need a check for the directory in `try_files` if you want the directory index loaded or autogenerated.

```
try_files $uri.ics $uri $uri/ =404;
```

Per the [documentation for the `try_files` directive](http://nginx.org/r/try_files):

> It is possible to check directory’s existence by specifying a slash at the end of a name, e.g. `$uri/`

In other words, `$uri` means "try a *file* at the given path", whereas `$uri/` means "try a *directory* at the given path", and the latter is what causes auto-indexing of that directory to kick in.

Comment: This works, but I don't understand why. If I visit `/calendar/` wouldn't `$uri == "/calendar/"` and `$uri/ == "/calendar//"`?

Comment: Did you click the link? It explains: It doesn't _actually_ append a `/`, but instead loads the directory index if available.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the link as I'm colorblind.

Comment: Blame the developers. They're hard to see for the rest of us, too. :)